# Ignore directory in RewriteRule - .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I searched in internet for this, found alot of solutions but none of them worked.

I am using shared hosting and in this hosting all the websites data are in one public_html folder.

I have .htaccess file in public_html folder which is for my main site named "mainexample.com" and all the other websites have folders named according to their domain. e.g. "example1.com" and "example2.com".

I want to ignore these "example1.com" and "example2.com" folder only.

Below is my .htaccess code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# index file can be index.php, home.php, default.php etc.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://www.mainexample.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# condition with escaping special chars
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Ignore how and for what? What is happening that you want to ignore them?

Comment: @PanamaJack I do not want to apply my rewrite rules to specific folders. Which is named above as "example1.com" and "example2.com".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line to ignore selected folders:

```
RewriteRule ^(example1|example2)\.com(/|$) - [L,NC]
```